# Why does a saved attachment's file name include the name of the expected save folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

**I'm trying to:**

1. Check the email for attachments
2. If the email contains an attachment cycle through the method for each attachment in the email.
3. The method will search the attachment display name for a string match anywhere in the name, and assign it an ID accordingly
4. It will then save a copy of the attachment to the matching subfolder based on the ID if the attachment is a .pdf

**Issues I'm running into:**

- InStr doesn't seem to be assigning id's properly
- The macro is saving copies of the attachment, but it's renaming them to the file folder name, and doesn't seem to be sorting based on id.
- Once copies are saved, the only way I can delete them is through the cmd.

---

```
Public Sub ProcessEmails()

Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oItem As Object

Set oItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

For Each oItem In oItems
    If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then Call SaveAttachmentsToDisk(oItem)
Next oItem

End Sub



Private Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(oItem As Outlook.MailItem)

'Declares objAtt as an outlook attachment
Dim objAtt As Attachment
'Declares i as data type Integer
Dim i As Integer
'Declares objFSO as any Data Type
Dim objFSO As Object
'Declares sExt as data type string
Dim sExt As String
'Declares sSaveFolder as data Type string
Dim sSaveFolder As String

'Only proceed if the email contains attachements.
If oItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    'Cycle through each attachment on the email.
    For i = 1 To oItem.Attachments.Count
        Set objAtt = oItem.Attachments(i)

       'Get the extension of the attached file name.
        sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objAtt.FileName)

        'declares an Id used for file path routing
        Dim id As Integer

        'Checks the email attachment name for a string match. If a match occurs, assigns an ID used for file path routing
        Select Case True

        Case InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "APP", vbTextCompare) > 0
            id = "1"
        Case InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B - Asset", vbTextCompare) > 0
            id = "2"
        Case InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B - Business", vbTextCompare) > 0
            id = "3"
        Case InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B Fair", vbTextCompare) > 0
            id = "4"
        Case InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "BDL", vbTextCompare) > 0
            id = "5"
        Case Else

        End Select


        'Saves outlook attachment to 'sSaveFolder' declared path if file extension is 'pdf'
        If sExt = "pdf" Then
            'Saves attachment to related subfolder based on ID
            Select Case id
                Case "1"
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test1"
                Case "2"
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test2"
                Case "3"
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test3"
                Case "4"
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test4"
                Case "5"
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test5"
                Case Else
                    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test"
            End Select

            objAtt.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If


        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next i
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made quite a few changes to your code to clean up some things:

- I removed `id`, as it seems to serve no purpose. Why not just skip
  the assignment of `id` and go right to assigning the save paths?
- I've also moved all declarations to the top, as you shouldn't be using
  `Dim` inside a loop.
- I've removed a lot of the comments - comments should be reserved for 
  making clarifications where confusion can occur - no need to explain 
  that all your `Dim` lines are declarations, and what they're being declared as. If anything, just start that snippet with `'Declarations` if you feel the need to.

Also, `Select Case` is great - but you can't use `Select Case` to evaluate `True`. In your scenario, and `If/ElseIf` statement will suffice:

```
Public Sub ProcessEmails()

Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oItem As Object

Set oItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

For Each oItem In oItems
    If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then Call SaveAttachmentsToDisk(oItem)
Next oItem

End Sub

Private Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(oItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Attachment
Dim i As Integer
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim sExt As String
Dim sSaveFolder As String

'Only proceed if the email contains attachements.
If oItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For i = 1 To oItem.Attachments.Count
        Set objAtt = oItem.Attachments(i)

        sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objAtt.Filename)

        If sExt = "pdf" Then
            If InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "APP", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test1\"
            ElseIf InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B - Asset", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test2\"
            ElseIf InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B - Business", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test3\"
            ElseIf InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "B2B Fair", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test4\"
            ElseIf InStr(1, objAtt.DisplayName, "BDL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\test5\"
            Else
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test\"
            End If

            objAtt.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If

        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next i

    Set objFSO = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for expedient response and best practices!

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's still changing the naming convention of the attachment and routing everything to

    Else
                sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\jkassels\Desktop\test"

Comment: Is it saving them as `test4MyDocument` or something? I didn't notice you were missing some back slashes. I've added the back slashes, although unless you really have folders named `test` through `test5`, those might be unnecessary - I'll need your clarification.

Comment: Where are you trying to save these files to? Just to the `test` folder, or the `test1, test2, test3, test4, test5` folders *inside* this test folder?

Comment: I'm trying to route attachments to the subfolders _inside_ the `test` folder. If there's no match, default to the root `test` folder

Comment: The code should work now then - you were missing backslashes at the end of your file paths.

Comment: Thank you @dwirony